# Laravel Horizon limit the amount of total processes

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-horizon

After reading quite some posts ([Like this one from Zechariah Campbell](https://medium.com/@zechdc/laravel-horizon-number-of-workers-and-job-execution-order-21b9dbec72d7)) about Laravel Horizon with a Redis Queue and trying to configure it and customize it I couldn't find out if it's possible to maximize the total amount of processes run by laravel horizon.

Using the strategy "simple" and having one process per Queue (which is what I want) might cause cpu or internal memory issues when having like 1000 queues which will cause 1000 processes to run? (Every Queue gets their own process by default)

Is there any way to maximize the total amount of processes spawned by horizon, regardless of the amount of queues? So 10 processen en 20 queues and when one queue is empty or even better one job of one queue was processed, the worker will pick another queue?

My current configuration

horizon.php

```
'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'balance'    => 'simple',
                'processes'  => 1,
                'tries'      => 2,
            ],
        ],
```

queue.php

```
'redis' => [
            'driver'      => 'redis',
            'connection'  => 'queue',
            'queue'       => "1000,2000,3000",
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for'   => null,
        ],
```

laravel 5.8 and horizon 3.0

currently I use beanstalkd but want to migrate to redis queue with horizon because of the lack of maintainance of beanstalkd and some nasty bugs.

UPDATE 2019-05-17:

I tried the config maxProcesses:

```
'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'balance'    => 'simple',
                'maxProcesses' => 1,
                'processes'  => 1,
                'tries'      => 2,
            ],
        ],
```

But even then three processes are created, one for each queue.
[image]

Comment: there is maxProcesses and minProcesses check https://divinglaravel.com/introduction-to-how-laravel-horizon-works post

Comment: see updated answer, not commented because of readability

Comment: i think overall what are you looking for is  balance=> "auto"

Comment: no, I don't want two or more processes handle one queue, which is what this auto balancing option does. I just tried but this also create three processes, one for each queue. I want 10 processes to handle for example 100 queues without two workers processing one queue.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/43ya3c/maximum_number_of_queue_workers/ i think this might help

Comment: What does this old post has to do with my question?

Comment: he is trying to know best Queue Workers numbers but there is no clear answer

Comment: I know, but horizon is the application/process managing the actual worker processes. Somehow I need to configure the max.

Comment: i think the default max processes are 1 try change it also try change the Memory limit of every worker.

Comment: Where did you find that limiting the max memory limit per queue worker will cause the default of one worker per queue to change?

Comment: i just say try changing it https://divinglaravel.com/introduction-to-how-laravel-horizon-works

Comment: This might not be welcome but in a cloud-first world you should probably be thinking about one or more entire instances per Queue.   We use ECS to run Horizon and trying to micromanage a given server execution doesn't really seem like time well spent.  Let your cloud provider do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

As of Horizon 4 (and previous versions), it will always assign at least 1 worker to each queue. There's no way around it.
So, if your `minProcess` is 1 but you have 3 queues then you'll have at least 3 processes (workers). I guess the `minProcess` setting is more of a `minProcessPerQueue` thing.

Comment: `minProcess = 0`

Comment: @satnhak setting `minProcess = 0` doesn't work - Horizon will log `The value of [supervisor-1.minProcesses] must be greater than 0.`